# Elasticsearch aggrestions not shown in response of ajax call

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following ajax call to get data from elasticsearch. My problem is that the response does not have the expected 'aggregations' field.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://elasticsearch.net:80/tenant/_search' ,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
            "size": 0,
            "aggs": {
              "group_by_user_name": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "user_name"
                }
              }
            }
          },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});

Object {took: 2, timed_out: false, _shards: Object, hits: Object}
_shards: Object
hits: Object
hits: Array[0]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
max_score: 0
total: 3967
__proto__: Object
timed_out: false
took: 2
__proto__: Object
```

I've tried the request with curl and I see the 'aggregations' field. Any idea why I can't access this field in an ajax response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this stackoverflow post: [Querying dynamic aggregation in elasticsearch with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305271/querying-dynamic-aggregation-in-elasticsearch-with-ajax)

Essentially, you need to use POST rather than GET.

What does your curl request look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use POST instead of GET. When you are using GET , it disregards your body and provides the top hits alone.
Your CURL equal-ant of the query is as follows -

```
curl -XPOST http://elasticsearch.net:80/tenant/_search -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_user_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_name"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried POST earlier but I was getting a 400 error (Failed to derive xcontent from org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.ChannelBufferBytesReference). I played with it again and realized that what I was missing is converting the javascript object to JSON string:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://elasticsearch.net:80/tenant/_search' ,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({"size": 0,"aggs": {"group_by_user_name": {"terms": {"field": "user_name"}}}}),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

BTW, the curl request works with both GET and POST.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are doing something like curl -XGET URL -d QUERY, I don't think that is a GET request - seems like that might turn into a POST according to man pages.

Comment: You're right. XGET, POST and XPOST return aggregations but not GET.